# how to fetch user info by uid swift 3 firebase

Tags: authentication, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase swift 3. I am new in firebase. So I build an application which user can sign up and post an event, other user can view events and click on attend button if they want to attend. Successfully I can implement all this but my problem is when user click on attend button it will save as user uid under peoplewhoattend child. now I want to view those people who will attend the event. I think I should link user uid to user profile but I can not do that. I have tried a lot and find some similar question but nothing work with me. Here is my code. Rhanks in advance for every positive comment and help

#### this is attend action button

```
 @IBAction func btnAttend(_ sender: Any) {

    self.btnattend.isEnabled = true
    let dbRef = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://event-f39cc.appspot.com")
      let key = dbRef.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
    let imageRef = storageRef.child("posts").child(uid).child("\(key).jpg")
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgEvent.image!, 0.5)


    dbRef.child("users").child("posts").child(self.EventId!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let updateattends = ["peopleWhoattend/\(key)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid , "UserEmail" : Auth.auth().currentUser?.email , "Username" : Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName]  as  [String: Any]






        dbRef.child("posts").child(self.EventId!).updateChildValues(updateattends, withCompletionBlock: {(error, reff) in

            if error == nil{
                dbRef.child("posts").child(self.EventId!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
                    if let properties = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let Attend = properties["peopleWhoattend"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
                            let count = Attend.count
                            self.lblattend.text = "\(count)"

                            let update = ["Attend" : count]
                            dbRef.child("posts").child(self.EventId!).updateChildValues(update)

                            self.btnattend.isHidden = false
                            // self.unlikeBtn.isHidden = false
                            //self.unlikeBtn.isEnabled = true
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
    dbRef.removeAllObservers()





}
```

#### my database on firebase in JASON format

```
<pre>
{
"posts" : {


"-KrbDH19ERe9Os5RrEin" : {
  "Attend" : 10,
  "Category" : "Film & Media",
  "Event date End" : "15/08/2017 10:47 PM",
  "Event date Start" : "15/08/2017 10:47 PM",
  "EventId" : "-KrbDH19ERe9Os5RrEin",
  "EventTitle" : "hhh",
  "Fee" : "6",
  "Location" : {
    "latitude" : 23.61349209999999,
    "longitude" : 58.5434909,
    "place name" : "Ruwi St, Muscat, Oman"
  },
  "User Email" : "salwa@hotmail.com",
  "author" : "abeer",
  "commentsId" : "-KrbDH19ERe9Os5RrEio",
  "description" : "Event Description : dsdss",
  "likes" : 3,
  "pathToImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/event-f39cc.appspot.com/o/events%2FhjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73%2F-KrbDH19ERe9Os5RrEin.jpg?alt=media&token=795f2555-f36d-49d7-9bdd-e521fcd14c16",
  "peopleWhoLike" : {
    "-KrdnWbWtQ7zmkVwN7MZ" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-Krdnymu9a_zP81JFDzm" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KsZb-WL9dptWI7dHWDf" : "3IHHOBRaVyR3ldK4hGtcGoY7lox2"
  },
  "peopleWhoattend" : {
    "-KrbDLO6ZIpIxt4lTax0" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KrbDMri-KrHDrvCAHS4" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KrbE3OppAyB_zI5XacN" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KrbE3bgAZgvLs9J2KJr" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KrbE3vSo1Z6EqOAO4SJ" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KrbE4H_kpwgsMRlRCt6" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KrbE4Xa2CP_KXC8dQbi" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KtL2Egv2slRRk8f_rF1" : "H5kCOhIQFMbxQlN5dzZYC8aptxR2",
    "-KtL2TXGz5JkCd1vA3Z2" : "H5kCOhIQFMbxQlN5dzZYC8aptxR2",
    "-KtL2TtWdIFn3I1zvMAD" : "H5kCOhIQFMbxQlN5dzZYC8aptxR2"
  },
  "userId" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
  "username" : "Salwa"
},
"-KrdlVlme6Jc6eVbNBTa" : {
  "Attend" : 4,
  "Category" : "Science & Technology",
  "Event date End" : "20/08/2017 10:40 AM",
  "Event date Start" : "16/08/2017 10:40 AM",
  "EventId" : "-KrdlVlme6Jc6eVbNBTa",
  "EventTitle" : "hhhh",
  "Fee" : "6666",
  "Location" : {
    "latitude" : 23.6006718,
    "longitude" : 58.55438340000001,
    "place name" : "(Great Valley (Alkbir Wadi, Muscat, Oman"
  },
  "User Email" : "salwa@hotmail.com",
  "author" : "abeer",
  "commentsId" : "-KrdlVlme6Jc6eVbNBTb",
  "description" : "Event Description : ttttt",
  "likes" : 5,
  "pathToImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/event-f39cc.appspot.com/o/events%2FhjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73%2F-KrdlVlme6Jc6eVbNBTa.jpg?alt=media&token=4471c063-5432-474e-82b3-030f44ce231f",
  "peopleWhoLike" : {
    "-Krdlhj9fflCIEguJlPZ" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KrdlhtXEdxuUMRfYJsR" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-Krdlhz1914-GsfDsK21" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KsZDW38ka7dB5NtfrNm" : "Rufida",
    "-KsnWCXJNFlZJT5qbh8J" : "FWTfyvXqsXXdI9sy3GihCx8o5a63"
  },
  "peopleWhoattend" : {
    "-Krdlbv9aKWlYNGa1K_d" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-Krdldu17azum7ZH5u-E" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KrdlgBey4dkBLY8FBBK" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
    "-KtL2V0WEYwRLCLpGvvW" : "H5kCOhIQFMbxQlN5dzZYC8aptxR2"
  },
  "user name" : "rufida@hotmail.com",
  "userId" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
  "username" : "Salwa"
},
   "users" : {
"3IHHOBRaVyR3ldK4hGtcGoY7lox2" : {
  "name" : "Rufida",
  "uid" : "3IHHOBRaVyR3ldK4hGtcGoY7lox2",
  "urlToImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/event-f39cc.appspot.com/o/users%2F3IHHOBRaVyR3ldK4hGtcGoY7lox2.jpg?alt=media&token=1c3ee6f2-f688-40b4-b1d6-69f90bf19bb1"
},
"FWTfyvXqsXXdI9sy3GihCx8o5a63" : {
  "Email" : "Ola@hotmail.com",
  "name" : "Ola",
  "uid" : "FWTfyvXqsXXdI9sy3GihCx8o5a63",
  "urlToImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/event-f39cc.appspot.com/o/users%2FFWTfyvXqsXXdI9sy3GihCx8o5a63.jpg?alt=media&token=289d9b9c-65c1-4ac0-83e4-7f688925f927"
},
"H5kCOhIQFMbxQlN5dzZYC8aptxR2" : {
  "Email" : "Salwa@hotmail.com",
  "name" : "Salwa",
  "uid" : "H5kCOhIQFMbxQlN5dzZYC8aptxR2",
  "urlToImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/event-f39cc.appspot.com/o/users%2FH5kCOhIQFMbxQlN5dzZYC8aptxR2.jpg?alt=media&token=8f676259-7240-43d2-8735-0896ec9ad090"
},
"hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73" : {
  "name" : "abeer",
  "uid" : "hjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73",
  "urlToImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/event-f39cc.appspot.com/o/users%2FhjAPqucu2jh3sY6v9n9nRM5Fuz73.jpg?alt=media&token=2c343a4c-c6ad-4dcf-bd0d-10e9a7a635cb"
}
}
}
```

#### Attendess collection view to view  people who attend

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage


class AttendeesCollectionViewController:  UIViewController ,     UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource  {
var posts = [Events]()




@IBOutlet weak var CVAttendee: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 128.0/255.0, blue: 64.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]







    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    fetchEvents()

}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let height: CGFloat = view.frame.size.height
    let width: CGFloat = view.frame.size.width
    return CGSize(width: CGFloat(width * 0.95), height: CGFloat(height * 0.75))
}









override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.posts.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! AttendeeCollectionViewCell

    //Creating the cell
    cell.lblFirstName.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].FirstName
  cell.lblLastName.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].LastName



    cell.lblNumberAttendee.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].Attend

    if let imagePath = self.posts[indexPath.row].userPic{
        cell.imgUser.downloadImage(from: imagePath)
    }
    else{
        cell.imgUser.image = UIImage(named: "abstract-user-flat-4")
    }




    cell.EventId = self.posts[indexPath.row].EventId
    cell.lblEmail.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].Email

    cell.lblPhoneNum.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].PhoneNumber



    return cell
}





func fetchEvents(){






    let dbRef = Database.database().reference()
    dbRef.child("Attendee").queryOrdered(byChild: "EventId").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postData = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]


        for(_ ,value ) in postData{

            let event = Events()

                if
                    let FirstName = value["UserFirstName"] as? String,
                    let LastName = value["UserLastName"] as? String,
                    let Email = value["Email"] as? String,
                    let PhoneNumber = value["PhoneNumber"] as? String,
                    let attendingID = value["attendingID"] as? String,                    //    let NumberAttend = value["Event date End"] as? String,

                    let pathToImage = value["pathToImage"] as? String,
                    let EventId = value["EventId"] as? String,
                                         let userId = value["userId"] as? String {


                    event.FirstName = FirstName
                    event.LastName = LastName
                    event.Email = Email
                    event.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber
                    event.pathToImage = pathToImage
                 //   event.dateStart = NumberAttend
                    event.EventId = EventId
                    event.userId = userId
                    event.attendingID = attendingID

                    dbRef.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                        let users = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                        for(_ ,userVal) in users {
                            if let uid = userVal["uid"] as? String{
                                if uid == userId{




                                    if let img = userVal["urlToImage"] as? String{
                                        event.userPic = img
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })

                    dbRef.child("Attendee").observe(.value, with: { (snap)  in
                        // post.commentCount = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(snap.childrenCount)))
                        let comments = snap.value as! NSDictionary
                        for key in (comments.allKeys) {
                            if key as! String == attendingID{
                                let attendee = comments.value(forKey: attendingID) as! NSDictionary
                                if let attending = attendee.value(forKey: "Attendees"){
                                    let attending = attending as? NSDictionary
                                   // event.commentCount = messages?.count
                                }
                                else{
                                 //   event.commentCount = 0
                                }
                                self.CVAttendee.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    })





                    self.posts.append(event)
                }
            }
        })

    dbRef.removeAllObservers()
}
}
```

#### Events class

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


class Events: NSObject {

var author: String!
var Email: String!
var likes: Int!
var Attend : String!
var commentId: String!
var  attendingID : String!
var pathToImage: String!
var userId: String!
var userPic: String!
var EventId: String!
var dateStart: String!
var dateEnd: String!
var desc: String!
var Category: String!
var Fee: String!
var EventTitle: String!
var commentCount: Int!
var SponsorPakage  : String!
var locationAddress: NSDictionary!
var peopleWhoLike: [String] = [String]()
var peopleWhoattend: [String] = [String]()
var FirstName: String!
var LastName: String!
var PhoneNumber : String!

var go: goingStatus!

















}
```

#### Firebase picture

[post child firebase database shootscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6H16.png)

[user child firebase shootscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2TpK.png)